# Calculate mean value for ID keeping Panel Data Shape

Tags: r, panel, transformation

Good afternoon,
I have the following problem hope that somebody could help me find the right solution. 
The situation is as following:
Suppose, one has an unbalanced panel dataset

```
| ID |  Value  |  Time  |
| 1  |   12    |  2011  | 
| 1  |    8    |  2012  |
| 1  |   10    |  2013  |
| 2  |   24    |  2011  |
| 2  |   10    |  2012  |
| 3  |    1    |  2011  |
| 3  |    8    |  2012  |
| 3  |    2    |  2013  |
```

What I try to do is to calculate the mean of value for each ID, and plug this one value for each year of that individual. The results should look like this:

```
| ID |  Value  |  Time  |
| 1  |   10    |  2011  | 
| 1  |   10    |  2012  |
| 1  |   10    |  2013  |
| 2  |   17    |  2011  |
| 2  |   17    |  2012  |
| 3  |    4    |  2011  |
| 3  |    4    |  2012  |
| 3  |    4    |  2013  |
```

I've seen many questions of the same type, but there was no solution that keep the panel data form. Does anyone has an idea how to solve this in R?

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3), 
                 Value = c(12,8,10,24,10,1,8,2), 
                 Time = c(2011,2012,2013,2011,2012,2011,2012,2013))

df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(Value = round(mean(Value))) %>% 
  right_join(df %>% select(-Value), by ="ID")

# A tibble: 8 x 3
     ID Value  Time
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1    10  2011
2     1    10  2012
3     1    10  2013
4     2    17  2011
5     2    17  2012
6     3     4  2011
7     3     4  2012
8     3     4  2013
```

EDIT

As Sotos points out below, this is a better solution:

```
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(Value = round(mean(Value)))
```

Comment: Why not just simply use `mutate` and be done with it? `df %>% group_by() %>% mutate(value = mean(Value)))`

Comment: Because I haven't finished my first coffee of the day yet. (You missed out `ID` from `group_by` and it looks like `Value` should be rounded to the nearest integer.)

Comment: Hehe...the coffee... of course :) (Note: I did not miss the ID, I was simply drafting a sample of mutate... I m not that careless - except maybe on Mondays))

Answer (score 1):

With `data.table` this becomes a "one-liner":

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, Value := round(mean(Value)), by = ID][]
```

> ```
>       ID Value  Time
> 1:     1    10  2011
> 2:     1    10  2012
> 3:     1    10  2013
> 4:     2    17  2011
> 5:     2    17  2012
> 6:     3     4  2011
> 7:     3     4  2012
> 8:     3     4  2013
> ```

#### Data

```
df <- fread(
  "| ID |  Value  |  Time  |
| 1  |   12    |  2011  | 
| 1  |    8    |  2012  |
| 1  |   10    |  2013  |
| 2  |   24    |  2011  |
| 2  |   10    |  2012  |
| 3  |    1    |  2011  |
| 3  |    8    |  2012  |
| 3  |    2    |  2013  |",
  sep = "|", drop = c(1L, 5L))
```

Answer (score 1):

The base R solution via `ave`,

```
round(ave(df$Value, df$ID))
#[1] 10 10 10 17 17  4  4  4
```